# Docker Run results in a FileNotFound error even though the file does exist

Tags: java, docker, filenotfoundexception

I built a docker container using a Java project with no problems.

```
$docker build -t myproj .
```

The Dockerfile contains the parameters that the project needs to run.  One of them is the input file.  The input file is:

```
/home/user/myproj/files/input.csv
```

Here are the lines in the **Dockerfile** in **/home/user/myproj** that set the variable for one of the project parameters.

```
ENV INPUT_FILE /home/user/myproj/files/input.csv
...
export INPUT_FILE=/home/user/myproj/files/input.csv
```

Yet when I run the Java code, I get the error message:

```
$ docker run myproj

FileNotFoundException: /home/user/myproj/files/input.csv does not exist
```

Yet when I do an **ls -l /home/user/myproj/files/input.csv** the file does show as existing.  Does anybody know why the project claims the file doesn't exist, when in fact it does, and the parameter is passed correctly?  I am new to Docker and am thoroughly stumped.

Comment: Are you listing that file from inside the container or on the host?

Comment: I am listing the full path on the host.  Should I do it from inside the container?  I think it would just be files/input.csv, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers do not have access to the hosts filesystem by default.

Assuming that you have copied in the source while building, or volume mounted it in, you may have to do this for your config file as well.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Check out your RW permissions for the file as well, in the event that you're not running the process as `root`

If you've got a Dockerfile, it would be handy to add to the post (With sensitive information redacted of course)

Comment: Thanks.  I had an inkling the problem would be something like that.  The weird thing about the platform I am running it on is that my home directory doesn't have enough disk space, so I have to use one of the root directories and run it using sudo.  I think that is what has been fouling things up.

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't have thought that the folder being owned by root would be troublesome, unless it had some very strict Read rules.

To confirm, are you mounting the config file in using something like the following?
`docker run --rm -v /home/user/myproj/files/input.csv:/home/user/myproj/files/input.csv myimage`

Comment: No.  I didn't do that.  Unfortunately, I am out of the office until next Wednesday, so I won't be able to try it until then.  The ideal thing would be to get more disk space on my home drive, but I don't think that is possible.  Our project is king-sized; even zipped it won't copy over.
Thank you, though, that might solve it.  I'll let you know once I try it.

Comment: Looking forward to hearing about it, as said the container explicitly needs the file to be included, either via `COPY` or mounting `-v`. Hoping it resolves your issue :-)